# How to split an SQL file by query?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I need to load an SQL file (e.g. produced by `pg_dump`) and execute it in Node.js using [`node-postgres`](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) with the native driver. However, `node-postgres` [only allows to execute one query at a time](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2100). To work around this limitation, I need to split the SQL file into individual SQL statements.

What is the correct way to split the file (in Node.js) into multiple queries?

Comment: Do you need to execute it in Node? Can you use `pg_restore`?

Comment: SQL file produced by `pg_dump` was just an example. Authentication and error handling needs to be done in Node.js.

Comment: Did you figure out a way? I have a similar issue